# What to do with my useless question?

Tags: support

I asked a question about how to work around an error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113109/check-if-a-named-capture-group-was-found

While I waited for an answer, I played around my code, the error disappeared, my original code works. Wonders. Or maybe I had a typo in the original code, who knows.

Meanwhile, answers were made to not encounter that error. The answers are interesting, but the error actually doesn't happen. So I don't know if I should accept one of the answers, ask the moderators for deletion (can't delete it myself since it has answers) or something else ?

Comment: Seems to me that you didn't add quotes around your regexp, if so it would be closed as a typographical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest, keep the question as it is.

You should try to figure out what caused the error, and then make an edit to your question(if needed to explain the error again).

SO is known to provide best suggestions/answers possible and every good question is treated as an archive.

So, let the question be there. If needed, try to explain what your actual issue was. Also if you can figure it out, you can put a self-answer as well. That will state how you overcame your problem.

Or, if it is just a typo error, then somebody may flag it for a close.

Comment: As Spencer Wieczorek guessed in comment, it was probably a typo or something like that, since what I intended to do in the first place actually works without any fix needed. So I don't see how any usefull answer could be found.

Comment: Can he raise a flag on his own question?

Comment: I can only flag for moderator attention on my own post

Comment: Somewhere I saw people saying that flagging own posts for moderator attention isn't preferable. :(

Comment: I was under the same impression. As such, someone else should flag it. I'll make an edit to make clear I'm not waiting for an answer.

Comment: Yes, that seems the best solution. :)